# Efficiently change order of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3 dimensional numpy array. The dimension can go up to 128 x 64 x 8192. What I want to do is to change the order in the first dimension by interchanging pairwise.

The only idea I had so far is to create a list of the indices in the correct order.

```
order    = [1,0,3,2...127,126]
data_new = data[order]
```

I fear, that this is not very efficient but I have no better idea so far

Comment: So, `data[order]` works for you, but you think that could be inefficient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could reshape to split the first axis into two axes, such that latter of those axes is of length `2` and then flip the array along that axis with `[::-1]` and finally reshape back to original shape.

Thus, we would have an implementation like so -

```
a.reshape(-1,2,*a.shape[1:])[:,::-1].reshape(a.shape)
```

Sample run -

```
In [170]: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(6,3))

In [171]: order = [1,0,3,2,5,4]

In [172]: a[order]
Out[172]: 
array([[0, 8, 5],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [0, 0, 2],
       [7, 3, 8],
       [1, 6, 3],
       [2, 4, 4]])

In [173]: a.reshape(-1,2,*a.shape[1:])[:,::-1].reshape(a.shape)
Out[173]: 
array([[0, 8, 5],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [0, 0, 2],
       [7, 3, 8],
       [1, 6, 3],
       [2, 4, 4]])
```

Alternatively, if you are looking to efficiently create those constantly flipping indices `order`, we could do something like this -

```
order = np.arange(data.shape[0]).reshape(-1,2)[:,::-1].ravel()
```